# User Inputed Values to be part of a function to change the values in the column of a dataframe?

Tags: python

Previously in the code, I get the user to input two values called PosCtrl and NegCtrl. I want to use these values in a function applied to a column in a dataframe.

I have a dataframe (RawStacked) of two columns, number and cell_value. I want to transform this RawStacked dataframe into another dataframe (NormStacked) in which the values in the cell_value column are normalized using the user inputted values. The normalization equation is:

```
    x - NegCtrl
------------------- x 100
 PosCtrl - NegCtrl
```

I tried this:

```
NormStacked = RawStacked.apply(lambda x: ((x - NegCtrl)/(PosCtrl - NegCtrl)*100))
```

But that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I think the syntax of the math is wrong or something, but I don't know how. I tested a simpler equation to see if it worked and it did:

```
NormStacked = RawStacked.apply(lambda x: (x + 1))
```

This works perfectly fine, but it's not the equation I want to use to transform my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply formula to whole dataFrame . Apply it to specific column.

NormStacked = RawStacked['cell_value'].apply(lambda x: ((x - NegCtrl)/(PosCtrl - NegCtrl)*100))